# Why isn't it possible to map $\mathbb R^5$ to $\mathbb R^6$ if $A$ is a $6\times 5$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd like to understand this intuitively as well, but from a mathematical standpoint, I understand that a $6\times 5$ matrix would inherently yield a row of zeros in RREF, but what I don't understand is, it's still possible for me to multiply a $6\times 5$ matrix by a vector in $\mathbb R^5$ and yield a vector in $\mathbb R^6$, so why can't it map?

What am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Do you mean to ask why such a mapping cannot be surjective (onto)?

Comment: @SeanRoberson wait a minute...that would make more sense lmfao.

Comment: @SeanRoberson so essentially a linear transformation can be constructed but it just won't be a surjective mapping?

Comment: @EAO123 Exactly. You can certainly have a mapping between $\mathbb R^5$ and $\mathbb R^6$, but if that mapping is linear, then it will not be surjective.

Comment: Btw, for formulas and mathematical expressions, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.

Comment: @SeanRoberson got it, thanks! have to keep on reminding myself that "onto" is synonymous with "surjective" lol

Comment: This has been great!